# Sliding doesn't flow with floated elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm having an issue with my toggle function combined with the slide effect.  I am trying to slide out a div element, which is floated, and have the neighboring div element (also floated left) slide to take it's place.  When I use jQuery UI as in the example below the slide animation is correct (just a slide left), but the floated element next to it waits until the animation is complete before moving.

[With jQuery UI](http://jsfiddle.net/brombomb/uEGAv/)

In this example without jQuery UI, the neighboring element slides over as the other is sliding out, making for a very smooth transition.  In this case the slide has both a left and top animation which is not what I am trying to achieve.

[Without jQuery UI](http://jsfiddle.net/brombomb/5y9b9)

I'm trying to find a solution for using jQuery UI as it's already embedded in my site for other features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is I have done something similar that you are looking for. [Jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uEGAv/1/)

```
$('#toggle').bind('click',function() {
    $("#wrapper").toggleClass('collapse');
    if ($("#wrapper").hasClass('collapse')) {
    $('.collapse').animate({'margin-left':'-50px'});
    } 
    if (!$("#wrapper").hasClass('collapse')) {
    $('#wrapper').animate({'margin-left':'0'});
    }
});​

<div id="toggle">Slide</div>
<div id="space"></div>
<div id="wrapper"><div id="left">
</div>

<div id="right">
    <div>
</div>
​
#wrapper {
 overflow:hidden;
 maegin-left:0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  It looks good and definitely works.  Seems like a valid workaround.  If no one else comes up with anything I'll accept yours as  the answer.